# Will I be able to test this PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have 2 websites. One is currently hosted on a domain and one is just local on my computer (viewing it using brackets live preview).

I used the hosted website (#1) to create a mysql database.

Then for my local website (#2) I created a login page and created a index.php document to handle the submission. In the index.php of the local website I told it to connect to the mysql database of the hosted website.

Then when I try to preview the local page and submit it, I get this error

**"Cannot GET /POST?name=JohnDoe&password=123"**

So I am wondering, since my sql database is hosted online, can I actually test my website locally or not?

Comment: where is that error being shown?

Comment: If you use session or cookie it will be safe to the domain where was created. It's not possible, but you can use CURL to connect another website or connect to same database. Check domain policy.

Comment: There might be two problems: first, it's up to your specific hosting provider's permissions to allow remote connections to the MySQL database (and then, your user for that database being remote too), you must ask them if they allow them. Second, what seems wrong too is the request: unless you actually have a file called POST in your root (/).

Comment: @daremachine it seems to me that he is trying to connect to his hosting provider's MySQL server, not relaying the login data from his local instance to his hosted instance's form.

Comment: @PatoSáinz sure. But it can be causing he have wrong connection data. Check if your db provider can be accesed from remote and check your db user if can too

Comment: @daremachine and check if he's not connecting to 127.0.0.1 too.

Comment: @PatoSáinz on a blank page. The index.html dissapears and is replaced with a blank page with that message.

Comment: @PatoSáinz I am using 1&1 hosting... does that help?

Comment: I found this guide but have no idea how to do that. 



https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/administration-c37694/enable-remote-connections-to-mysql-a781586.html

Comment: @Badrush you'd have to ask them. And no, that guide you linked is not useful for you because you're using managed hosting and not a dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

If your provider doesn't allow direct access to MySQL port (usually 3306) from outside you are not able to use remote db.

I suggest you to try creating a dump of remote db and restore it in a local instance of MySQL. It's a better approach to develop in local and publish your modifications after testing with a database that can be modified, broked and restored as needed.